# howhow can I use uploadtype resumable in Drive.Files.insert() Drive API

Tags: file-upload, google-drive-api, resumable

I try to use Drive.Files.insert() for making more than 50mb csv in Google app script.(using Drve API)
the error message is Empty response. 
I read reference but there is no answer to do that.
here is code.

```
 var optionalArgs = { 
     uploadType: 'resumable',
    }; 
 var resource = {
                     title: fileName,
                     parents: [],
     };
 Drive.Files.insert(resource, blob, optionalArgs);
```

thank you for reading my message.

Comment: At Google Apps Script, the maximum blob size is 50 MB (52,428,800 bytes) and `Drive.Files.insert` cannot be used for the resumable upload. Unfortunately, this is the current specification. By the way, where is the CSV data you want to create as a CSV file?

Comment: thank you for answering my question.

I put each spreadsheet data in this code.

 temp.push(contents); 
    csv += temp.join(',') + "\r\n";
var blob = Utilities.newBlob('', contentType, fileName)
                      .setDataFromString(csv);

do you have any suggestion about that? 
thank you so much